# sscanf_s access violation when seperate string and integer

Tags: c++, scanf

```
    char a[200] = { 0 };

char tst[20] = "aaaa 123\n";
int i;
sscanf_s(tst, "%s %d",a, &i);
printf("reasult:%s %d", a,i);
```

No matter I use `char tst[20] = "aaaa 123\n";` or `char* tst = "aaaa 123\n";`,
it always shows access violation.
I need to seperate a string an integer from a string. But why this happens ?

Comment: Read this for more information on how to use it correctly. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t6z7bya3.aspx

Comment: `sprintf_s` gave me a bit of a surprise when it crashed the program on overflow rather than truncate the way `snprintf` does. `sscanf_s ` looks to have the same behaviour. Give https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ksazx244.aspx a read if you find the program dying unexpectedly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`sscanf_s`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) expects two arguments for `%c`, `%s` and `%[`, the second being the size of the buffer passed. The following should work:

```
sscanf_s(tst, "%s %d", a, sizeof(a), &i);
```

Comment: I wonder why the OP is using `sscanf_s` instead of `sscanf` if he doesn't understand the difference?

Comment: IIRC, MSVC actively discourages the unsafe (no buffer size) versions of those functions. You have to reenable them with a particular define.